Why is it cheaper to execute a transaction on L2 compared to L1?
I don't understand this fundamental concept. If L2 is a blockchain just like L1 then why is executing a transaction cheaper in L2? If L2 knows a way to run a single transaction (I'm not talking about rollups) and all its implications cheaper (state change) then why is this knowledge not replicated in L1 to make it more affordable for everyone?
I am really not getting this at all :)

L2 solutions trade off security and complete decentralisation for their lower transaction costs.
How L1 works ?
In L1 main chain transactions ,the transaction you make are processed and recorded on the main chain itself. Also L1 chains have consensus mechanisms (like PoS or PoW) that ensure the security and integrity of the network. These mechanisms are not easy to change without risking the overall security
How L2 Works ?
But when it comes to L2 , these are like chains built on top of the L1 , designed to improve scalability and reduce transaction cost by processing the transaction off-chain (we cant do it in main chain cause like it reduces the maximum decentralisation) or in a different manner and then anchoring to the main chain.
L2 solutions also batch multiple transactions together and then submit them to L1 as a single transaction. This reduces the cost per transaction because the L1 transaction fee is shared among all the batched transactions
Also the consensus mechanism of L2 is also less resource intensive than L1 chains , making it less secure .
L2 solutions significantly help in reducing network congestion, as L1 does not have to process every transaction individually. Instead, L1 only needs to verify and record the aggregated results or proofs from L2.
Summary
L1 Chain : Ensures security and decentralization with robust but resource-intensive consensus mechanisms. All transactions are processed and recorded directly on the main chain.
L2 Chains : Enhances scalability and reduces transaction costs by processing transactions off-chain or in a different manner and then anchoring them to L1. Uses less resource-intensive consensus mechanisms, which trade off some security and decentralization for efficiency.
Hope it helps :)
